# Python split string by multiple specific characters and keep the "delimiters"

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a list of compounds like this:

```
ex = ['CrO3', 'Cr8O21', 'NbCrO4']
```

And I would like to get the elements and numbers separately. Something like this:

```
['Cr','O',3]

['Cr',8,'O',21]

['Nb','Cr','O',4]
```

However, this HAS to be a general process - these will not always be the compounds I am working with.
I think this can be accomplished using regex and the split() function. However, I am having trouble finding the right regex expression that gets me what I want.

Here is what I have right now:

```
# elements to split by
split_elements = ['Cr','Nb','O']

def split(compound, split_elements):
    separated = []
    splitstr = ")|(?=".join([str(elem) for elem in split_elements]) 
    splitstr = '('+splitstr+')'
    # splitstr will end up like this: 
    # (Cr)|(?=Nb)|(?=O)

    result = list(filter(None,re.split(splitstr, compound)))
    separated.append(result)

    return(separated)

for item in ex:
    print(split(item, split_elements))
# Output
# [['Cr', 'O3']]
# [['Cr', '8O21']]
# [['Nb', 'Cr', 'O4']]
```

As you can see, the numbers are still attached, and I'm not sure why. I've searched for a similar issue, but I can't find any (and what I have right now is already the result of furious googling).

Does anyone have any solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` to decompose the chemical compounds.

```
>>> import re    
>>> ex = ['CrO3', 'Cr8O21', 'NbCrO4']
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]?|\d*', ex[0])
['Cr', 'O', '3']
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+', ex[1])
['Cr', '8', 'O', '21']
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+', ex[2])
['Nb', 'Cr', 'O', '4']
```

Although you should probably check out one of the many packages on PyPI that deal with chemistry if you plan to do anything more complicated.

Comment: `[a-z]*` is wrong, because IUPAC atomic symbols only ever have at most one lowercase following the (mandatory) uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use split, use `re.findall()` and write a regexp that matches either case: Uppercase optionally followed by lowercase, or any number of digits.

```
re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]?|\d+', compound)
```

Comment: I think this will work! I will update on whether it works on everything!

Answer (score 0):

The regex answers are good, though you could always write a dictionary or list with the elements.

`elements = [O, Cr, Nb, ...]`

Or look into libraries such as https://pubchempy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: How does that help with getting the numbers after the chemical symbols?