# Turning a string of chemical elements in a list containing the separate atoms

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to create a list from a string that contains a chemical formula as in the following example:

```
structuralFormula1 = 'OCaOSeOO'
```

In the list I want all the chemical atoms to be separated from each other, like this:

```
structuralFormula1_list = ['O', 'Ca', 'O', 'Se', 'O', 'O']
```

I have no idea how to begin solving this problem. Any tips would be very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just do a regex findall on capital letter, optional lower case letter

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296317/python-split-string-by-multiple-specific-characters-and-keep-the-delimiters answers your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `re.findall`:

```py
>>> import re
>>> ex = 'OCaOSeOO'
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]?', ex)
['O', 'Ca', 'O', 'Se', 'O', 'O']
```

---

**Regex explanation**:

- `[A-Z]` : Match uppercase letter
- `[a-z]` : Match lowercase letter
- `[A-Z][a-z]` : Match uppercase letter followed by lowercase letter
- `[A-Z][a-z]?` : Match uppercase letter followed by 0 or 1 lowercase letters
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` : Match uppercase letter followed by 0 or more lowercase letters. (* is greedy, it will match as many as found)

```py
>>> import re
>>> ex = 'OCaOSeOO'
>>> re.findall('[A-Z]', ex)
['O', 'C', 'O', 'S', 'O', 'O']
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]', ex)
['Ca', 'Se']
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]?', ex)
['O', 'Ca', 'O', 'Se', 'O', 'O']
>>>
```

**Edit #1**: For another example mentioned in the comments:

```py
>>> ex = 'ABbCccDdddEeeeeFfffffGggggggg'
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', ex)
['A', 'Bb', 'Ccc', 'Dddd', 'Eeeee', 'Ffffff', 'Gggggggg']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. I had never heard about this "re" module. I will try to incorporate your code into mine and see if it works.

Comment: What if I would have chemical elements consisting out of 3 letters? How can I change the number of letters of each atom in my list? For example, if in the code you wrote ex = 'ABbCccDdddEeeeeFfffffGggggggg'. The answer would need to be {'A': 1, 'Bb': 1, 'Ccc': 1, 'Dddd': 1, 'Eeeee': 1, 'Ffffff': 1, 'Gggggggg': 1} Is this something I can also include in the code?

Comment: @FedraHerman I have edited the answer to include the example that you mentioned. Notice the `*` and `?` characters. I have also added explanation for the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code seems to do the trick. I will incorporate it into my own code :)

Answer (score 1):

use `re.findall`

```
import re
re.findall('.[^A-Z]*', 'OCaOSeOO')
```

Output:

```
['O', 'Ca', 'O', 'Se', 'O', 'O']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you `re.split` with lookarounds:

```
import re
structuralFormula1 = 'OCaOSeOO'
print(re.split(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', structuralFormula1))
```

It splits at every position

- Not preceded by the beginning of the string: `(?<!^)` => this avoids a leading empty match
- Followed by an uppercase letter: `(?=[A-Z])`

Output:

```
['O', 'Ca', 'O', 'Se', 'O', 'O']
```